# show that $f\in C^{1}$ if $f_{n}$ is a sequence of twice differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-continuity, pointwise-convergence

Given a sequence of twice differentiable functions $f_{n}: E → R$  where $E$ is an interval,
suppose that $f_{n} → f$ pointwise to $E$, that $(f′_{n} (x_{0}))$ is bounded for some $x_{0}∈E$ and that $(f′′_{n})$ is uniformly bounded on $E$. Show that $f∈C^{1}$.

---

I have a idea to show this, first I want to use the theorem of continuity and uniformly convergence to show that sequence $f'$ is continuos , but I need to show that $(f_{n}')\rightarrow f'$ uniformly and I was looking in theorem of differentiable and uniformly convergence to do this and but again I need to show that sequence $(f′′_{n})\rightarrow f′′$ uniformly and I don't how I do after. If you can give me some advice ,I will be grateful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are considering a compact interval $[a,b]$. Let $c$ be any piont in $[a,b]$.

$(f_n')$ is equi-continuous since by MVT. By Arzela-Ascoli theorem there is a subsequence $(f_{n_i})$ converging uniformly to a continuous function $g$. Now $f(x)=\lim f_{n_i}(x)=\lim f_{n_i}(c)+\lim \int_c^{x} f_{n_i}' (t) dt=f(c)+\int_c^{x} g(t)dt$. Since $g$ is continuous it follows that $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: why you take $f(x)=\lim{f_{n_{i}}}=\lim {f_{n_{i}}}(0)+\lim \int_{0}^{x} f_{n_{i}}(t)dt$?

Comment: One way of showing thaa function is continuously differentiable is to show that it is theindefinite integral of some continuous function. @angieduque

Comment: But why you consider also $f(x)$ equal to $\lim f_{n_{i}}(0)$? Why you can consider the evaluation in zero?

Comment: @angieduque Answer edited.